# Convert to string to 'Proper' casing

Tags: sql, presto

Is there a way to convert a string to 'Proper' casing? I'm using the Excel definition of 'Proper' which will format text such that the first letter of any word is capitalized and the remaining letters are lower case.

---

Sample Inputs | Outputs

[image]

---

I browsed the string function/operators [Presto documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html) so it seems like this isn't possible, but hoping someone here can prove me wrong!

Comment: No because that is JavaScript and I am using SQL @DM. Please see tags that are provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`regexp_replace`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#id3) to turn string into the title case:

```sql
select regexp_replace('Hell asdasd QWEEQ aWQW', '(\w)(\w*)', x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2]));
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| Hell Asdasd Qweeq Awqw |

Comment: I had a burning suspicion this would require regex which I'm a complete newbie on. What does the `x ->` do in this statement?

Comment: @urdearboy this is quite common syntax for anonymous functions (sometimes called lambda expressions) shared in this or similar form across different languages. in this case it is a function accepting a match (each group is returned as an element of array) and returning string. Please check out the linked doc.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Guru indeed, @Guru Strong